# How do I assign a custom range of values to a string character in c++?

Tags: c++, calendar, range

I need to make a calendar for an assignment and for that I need to assign a variable that updates itself as I iterate over the dates in order to keep track of the present day of the week for each output.

To be clearer, my variable `present_day` will keep updating as the for-loop runs from Monday to Tuesday to Wednesday etc... to Sunday and then back to Monday.

I have no clue how to assign a custom range to this variable. Is there a way? If so, how?

Comment: Can you explain in which way a simple `present_day = the_new_value;` inside the `for` loop doesn’t solve your problem?

Comment: Because the year needs to begin from whichever day the user specifies. And in order to check for the number of spaces to be left (for the first date to be entered under the correct day), I need to run a while/for loop.

Comment: I'm sorry if the queries are a little ridiculous. I'm a beginner and I'm just trying to work it all out as best as I can.

Comment: @ZainPeracha It's more that it's not really clear what you are asking than it being ridiculous. What `for` loop? Maybe add some (pseudo-)code showing what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: My idea was that as every new date is outputted, the present_day value would update to the day for the that date. Every time the present_day value reaches Sunday, the loop would end, the code would enter a new line, present_day would reset to Monday and the new week would begin until each month, and eventually each year ends.

Comment: I can't put any code here because I can't use my for-loop to increment the value of "present_day" every time it enters a new date.

Comment: "as every new date is outputted," what new dates? 30th February, 12th Nerober, stuff like that? Or a list of dates from some list somewhere? Try saying something like "I have a `std::vector` of unix timestamps. For each I want to output the day of the week".

Comment: I think I understand. You need to have a loop that will run over some range of numbers, but have some internal value that loops over 7 possible days? So you get 1:Monday, ..., 7:Sunday, 8:Monday, 9:Tuesday, etc?

Comment: [Something like this?](http://ideone.com/R1Jz66)

Comment: Yes, exactly like that! Thank you so much!

Comment: I have tweaked your question to be clearer given your indication that my suggested answer is helpful. Is it asking the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`put_time`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/put_time/) to do something clever here. This is an example on the range [0, 13):

```
tm foo;

for(auto i = 0; // 0 is the begining of your range
    i < 13; // 13 is the end of your range
    ++i){
    foo.tm_wday = i % 7;
    cout << put_time(&foo, "%A") << endl;
}
```

You can see I'm just dumping default values in [`tm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) except for the `tm_wday` field.